# Assembly.Load() Duplicate type with name ' '

Tags: c#, .net

NET EXE file from memory with Assembly.Load() function but when i give my byte array to this function I get a `BadImageFomatException` Duplicate type with name ... in assembly.

[image]

my code is:

```
try{
                    // prepare the Form to show balloontip
                    frmDefault frm = new frmDefault();

                    // prepare to load the application into memory (using Assembly.Load)

                    // read the bytes from the application exe file
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                    byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                    fs.Close();
                    br.Close();

                    // load the bytes into Assembly
                    Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bin);
                    // search for the Entry Point
                    MethodInfo method = a.EntryPoint;
                    if (method != null)
                    {

                        // create an istance of the Startup form Main method
                        object o = a.CreateInstance(method.Name);
                        Console.Write("Application started!");
                        method.Invoke(o, null);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // impossible to launch the application
                        Console.Write("Application error!");
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
```

Comment: It'd probably be more helpful to post the code before the exception instead of the code after.  Also, where does this code live? Can it be called more than once?  Is it the same as an assembly that's already been referenced or loaded?

Comment: From where did you get that assembly? And judging by the name of the type in question, is it obfuscated?

Comment: it's Can't called more than once.

Comment: and exe is not obfuscated

Answer (score 0):

First:

> ```
>  // read the bytes from the application exe file
>  FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
>  BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
>  byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
>  fs.Close();
>  br.Close();
>
>  // load the bytes into Assembly
>  Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bin);
> ```

Can be replaced with:

```
var a = Assembly.LoadFile(filePath);
```

About the problem, it seems you are loading 2 diferent versions from same binary file. Double from where you are loading the files.

Comment: ok i checked my exe file and it was have two assembly information but now i get "Bad IL Format" any idea ?

Comment: `LoadFile` will lock the assembly on disk, it is not the same.

Comment: i can't use Assembly.LoadFile i need to load from byte array

Comment: @leppie as reason, the file will be locked, and this should be used only when the `LoadFrom`not work, as [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8(v=vs.110).aspx) say.

Comment: @user3001228 another thing that can be causing the error is the weird character you have in filename. Prolly you are reading bytes wrongly.